# Filter comma separated values in Tableau [ Filter Paramters with unique values ]

Tags: filter, parameters, tableau-api, calculated-field

My table has two columns,

```
X_ID                                                     Code

234324_sfsdf_ADA, INT                                  ADA, INT      `

343424_gdfg234_LMR                                        LMR 

1233_dfgdfg_QXT                                           QXT

5423_tsdg_OLI                                             OLI
```

I want to create a new filter in Tableau which has unique values of codes as [ADA, INT, LMR, QXT, OLI] and then I need to check in X_ID Column if the code appears in X_ID.

For now, what i have done is

1. Separated the code into two columns code1, code2
2. I have created a parameter named "parameter1" which has all unique values from code1, code2
3. Then I am creating a calculated field where i check

`IF CONTAINS([X_ID],[Parameter1]) THEN [Parameter1] END`

The output of above step is ,

> parameter1 = [ADA,INT,LMR,QXT,OLI]

The problem here is that Parameter1 only checks for its first value. So, In my case the Parameter1 has first value as ADA. So, the condition of `CONTAINS([X_ID],[Parameter1])` is checked only for value ADA and not other values of parameter1.

My questions are:

1. What should be done so that for all the values of parameters the X_ID is checked.
2. If that's not possible is there any other way to achieve this task

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what exactly you are doing there, but try it this way:

1. Create a parameter with all unique code values you might have
2. Create a calculated field `CodeFilter` with `CONTAINS(LOWER([Code]), LOWER([Parameter]))` (The `LOWER()` makes sure that you don't run into problems in case there are mixed case values)
3. Drag `[CodeFilter]` to the filter shelf and filter for `True` values

That should create a filter to fit your requirements

Comment: But the problem still exist, because when I access parameter  values only the first value in the parameter is checked and not the other values. So For example my parameter has values as, [ ADA, CSA, DPP, DVC, HIP ] When i use Contains(Lower(parameter)), only ADA is checked against all the rows and no other value of the parameter is considered.

Comment: Do you want to check for only one code or for a combination of codes?

Comment: So there is a column which may have combination of the codes {ABC,LMN} , {ADX}, {FDC}, {ABC},{FDC,ADX}. SO what i want is, [1] create a filter on these codes but these codes in filter should be unique codes and not the combination of codes as comma separated values. Something like this [ ABC, LMN, ADX, FDC] [ 2] On selection of values return the rows which have these codes in it. So for example I select ADX as filter value it should return row 2 and row 5 as { ADX} and {FDC,ADX}

Comment: Ok, that's what I understood initially. Can you check if you have spaces somewhere in your parameter values? Generally it should work with that method.